Bringing TextFields into View in Jetpack Compose
I'm having trouble understanding how imePadding() and BringIntoViewRequester() work.
I have made a signup view and I believe I have applied imePadding correctly to the text field modifiers.
But for the view requesters I read in this medium article that you need to have multiple view requesters for multiple textfields. When I click on a textfield that's under the keyboard it does not come into view.
Am I meant to apply the view requesters to the AppSurface Composable or the overarching Column in SignupView?
Is there a better way to structure the view so that the textfields snaps just above the keyboard and comes into view?
I've also looked at focus requester which I don't think is the right use case for this.
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun SignupView(
    navController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: SignupViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val context = LocalContext.current

    // Variables to show the user error messages
    var showFieldErrorDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var showEULAToast by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var eulaItem by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    // Variables for EULA bottom sheet
    val skipPartiallyExpanded by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(skipPartiallyExpanded = skipPartiallyExpanded)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    // Variables used for IME handling
    // TODO text fields not coming into view when clicked
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    val fNameViewRequester = remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }
    val lNameViewRequester = remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }
    val emailViewRequester = remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }
    val passViewRequester = remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }
    val passCheckRequester = remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }

    // Handles bottom sheet state
    LaunchedEffect(eulaItem) {
        if (eulaItem.isNotEmpty()) {
            sheetState.show()
        } else {
            sheetState.hide()
        }
    }

    AppSurface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(scrollState),
        content = {
            // Top Component
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    PrimaryText(text = stringResource(R.string.hello_there))
                    PageTitleText(text = stringResource(R.string.create_an_account))
                }
                LightDarkSwitcher(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(50.dp)
                        .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                )
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                Row {
                    CustomOutlinedTextField(
                        // First Name Field
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                            .imePadding()
                            .bringIntoViewRequester(fNameViewRequester)
                            .onFocusEvent { focusState ->
                                if (focusState.isFocused) {
                                    scope.launch {
                                        fNameViewRequester.bringIntoView()
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        label = stringResource(R.string.first_name),
                        icon = Icons.Outlined.Person,
                        onValueChange = {
                            viewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.FirstNameChanged(it.trim()))
                        },
                        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                            capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Words,
                            imeAction = ImeAction.Next
                        ),
                        passStatus = viewModel.uiState.firstNamePass
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
                    CustomOutlinedTextField(
                        // Last Name Field
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                            .imePadding()
                            .bringIntoViewRequester(lNameViewRequester)
                            .onFocusEvent { focusState ->
                                if (focusState.isFocused) {
                                    scope.launch {
                                        lNameViewRequester.bringIntoView()
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        label = stringResource(R.string.last_name),
                        icon = Icons.Outlined.Person,
                        onValueChange = {
                            viewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.LastNameChanged(it.trim()))
                        },
                        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                            capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Words,
                            imeAction = ImeAction.Next
                        ),
                        passStatus = viewModel.uiState.lastNamePass
                    )
                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                CustomOutlinedTextField(
                    // Email Field
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .imePadding()
                        .bringIntoViewRequester(emailViewRequester)
                        .onFocusEvent { focusState ->
                            if (focusState.isFocused) {
                                scope.launch {
                                    emailViewRequester.bringIntoView()
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    label = stringResource(R.string.email),
                    icon = Icons.Outlined.Email,
                    onValueChange = {
                        viewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.EmailChanged(it.trim()))
                    },
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email,
                        imeAction = ImeAction.Next
                    ),
                    passStatus = viewModel.uiState.emailPass
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                CustomOutlinedTextField(
                    // Password Field
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .imePadding()
                        .bringIntoViewRequester(passViewRequester)
                        .onFocusEvent { focusState ->
                            if (focusState.isFocused) {
                                scope.launch {
                                    passViewRequester.bringIntoView()
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    isPassword = true,
                    label = stringResource(R.string.password),
                    icon = Icons.Outlined.Lock,
                    onValueChange = {
                        // Do not trim password, passes through `Validator`
                        viewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.PasswordChanged(it))
                    },
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password,
                        imeAction = ImeAction.Next
                    ),
                    passStatus = viewModel.uiState.passwordPass
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
                Column {
                    // Current Password Requirements
                    PasswordCondition(
                        passStatus = viewModel.uiState.passwordLengthPass,
                        label = "At least 6 characters long"
                    )
                    PasswordCondition(
                        passStatus = viewModel.uiState.passwordSpecialCharPass,
                        label = "Includes a special character"
                    )
                    PasswordCondition(
                        passStatus = viewModel.uiState.passwordUppercasePass,
                        label = "Includes an uppercase character"
                    )
                    PasswordCondition(
                        passStatus = viewModel.uiState.passwordNumberPass,
                        label = "Includes a number"
                    )
                    PasswordCondition(
                        passStatus = viewModel.uiState.passwordWhitespacePass,
                        label = "No whitespace characters"
                    )
                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
                CustomOutlinedTextField(
                    // Confirm Password Field
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .imePadding()
                        .bringIntoViewRequester(passCheckRequester)
                        .onFocusEvent { focusState ->
                            if (focusState.isFocused) {
                                scope.launch {
                                    passCheckRequester.bringIntoView()
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    isPassword = true,
                    label = stringResource(R.string.confirm_password),
                    onValueChange = {
                        // Do not trim password, passes through `Validator`
                        viewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.ConfirmPasswordChanged(it))
                    },
                    icon = Icons.Outlined.Lock,
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password,
                        imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                    ),
                    passStatus = viewModel.uiState.confirmPasswordPass
                )
                AuthCheckboxComponent(
                    // EULA Component
                    onCheckedChange = {
                        // Clear focus when clicked on EULA
                        viewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.EULACheckboxClicked(it))
                        focusManager.clearFocus()
                    },
                    onTextClicked = { eulaItem = it },
                    passStatus = viewModel.uiState.eulaPass
                )
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            // Bottom Component
            BottomComponent(
                textQuery = "Already have an account? ",
                textClickable = "Login",
                action = "Register",
                navController = navController,
                onButtonClicked = {
                    // Pass the NavHostController for signup handling
                    viewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.RegisterButtonClicked(navController))
                    if (!viewModel.isFormValid()) {
                        showFieldErrorDialog = true
                    }
                    if (!viewModel.isEulaAccepted() && viewModel.isFormValid()) {
                        showEULAToast = true
                    }
                },
                // Button is disabled when sign process is happening
                isEnabled = !viewModel.signupProgress
            )

            // Bottom Sheet for EULA
            if (eulaItem.isNotEmpty()) {
                ModalBottomSheet(
                    onDismissRequest = {
                        eulaItem = ""
                    },
                    sheetState = sheetState,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(0.9f),
                ) {
                    EULADisplay(eulaItem = eulaItem, closeButtonClicked = { eulaItem = "" })
                }
            }
            // Dialog when there are errors in the user fields
            if (showFieldErrorDialog) {
                AuthDialog(
                    onDismiss = { showFieldErrorDialog = false },
                    titleMessage = "Sign Up Error",
                    statusMessage = "Some information is incorrect"
                )
            }
            // Dialog when there is a signup error
            if (viewModel.errorMessage != null) {
                AuthDialog(
                    onDismiss = { viewModel.clearErrorMessage() },
                    titleMessage = "Signup Failed",
                    statusMessage = viewModel.errorMessage ?: "An unknown error has occurred"
                )
            }
            // Toast message when EULA is not checked
            if (showEULAToast) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please accept the Terms and Conditions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                showEULAToast = false
            }
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun AppSurface(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit,
    overlayingContent: @Composable () -> Unit = { }
) {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures(onTap = {
                    focusManager.clearFocus()
                })
            }
            .windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets.statusBars)
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Column(modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(28.dp)
                .imePadding()
            ) {
                content()
            }
            overlayingContent()
        }
        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .windowInsetsBottomHeight(WindowInsets.navigationBars)
        )
    }
}

Normal View
Confirm Password Field Clicked
